# Firefox strange JSON null respone

Tags: firefox, json

I was browsing a blog, I think made on wordpress, and when I clicked on an interal link I got a strange response, my firefox browser returned the JSON viewer with a NULL response.
Then I refreshed the url and I got the correct web page. What's wrong? Something with my firefox browser or an uncorrect response from the server?
Thank you

Comment: be more specific. Give version of Firefox. Is it uptodate? Are you working at localhost or remote?

Comment: Firefox 84.0.2. The issue doesn't appear when I am working. Just browsing a blog and firefox responds with the json viewer with NULL content when click links on the wordpress blog.

Comment: Is it regular behaviour? Try reinstall browser or restart computer. Do you have some remap keys from other application?

Comment: No, but, indeed, it seemed like I pressed some wrong keys and I activated some key shortcut to open JSON viewer. But I cannot be sure and I am a bit anxious if it's all ok with my browser... I made a deep antivirus scan an no malware on my pc has been found.